# Querying related content with tags, and content must match x amount of tags

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm having some difficulty querying for related content by tags, and ensuring that the content matches at least X amount of tags.

For example, on a "Case Study" page, underneath the case study content, links should be provided to link to other relevant case studies. However, another page, such as a product page, may have some similar tags and show up as relevant, when it's not. Only case studies should appear in that block.

So far, I have built up the query to retrieve related content based on the tags, but I am stuck on defining tags which MUST be present.

The following is my base 'more_like_this' query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "more_like_this": {
      "ids": [22],
      "fields": ["tags"],
      "min_doc_freq": 1,
      "min_term_freq": 1
    }
  },
  "fields": ["tags", "title", "id"]
}
```

And here is what I have so far in regards to defining required tags:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "more_like_this": {
          "ids": [
            22
          ],
          "fields": [
            "tags"
          ],
          "min_doc_freq": 1,
          "min_term_freq": 1
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "tag": "Case Study"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this just provides 0 hits :/

An example document would look like this:

```
{
    _index: tags
    _type: page
    _id: 21
    _version: 1
    _score: 1
    _source: {
      id: 21
      title: Why a Printing Company uses our CMS
      tags: [
          Case Study
          Case Study
          CMS
          Printing
      ]
      path: /case-study/why-a-printing-company-uses-our-cms
      updatedAt: {
          date: 2014-09-18 10:57:46.000000
          timezone_type: 3
          timezone: Europe/London
      }
    }
}
```

(Copy pasted from Head plugin, and so isn't valid JSON)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't understand. You have a `term` filter for one tag and you need to match the example document you provided?

Comment: @AndreiStefan the `term` filter would be dynamically altered by a PHP script depending on which tags were required. I'm trying to filter down related content (related by tags) based on certain tags that MUST be present

Comment: Try this, instead of that filter: `"query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "tags",
      "query": "Case Study"
    }
  }`.

Comment: What I posted above, actually, does match something else, as well (for example - "Another Case Study"). I posted an answer to cover the exact match.